# Nginx proxy_pass to IP but use HTTPS

Tags: nginx, tls, reverse-proxy

I have a legacy server that is secured via SSL certificate for `example.com`. I want to put another server infront of this one to `proxy_pass` certain (legacy) traffic. The new server must be exposed on `example.com` too.

If these were on separate domains (`legacy.example.com` and `example.com`), I would simply be able to `proxy_pass https://legacy.example.com`. However, the legacy app is littered with hardcoded `example.com` URLs (and it only has a SSL certificate for `example.com`). Any other URL (the IP for example) will redirect to `example.com`.

What I want to do, is `proxy_pass <legacy IP>`, set the host header with `proxy_set_header Host example.com`. But the issue is, this does not use HTTPS.

I did something a while back with curl, I was able to connect to a server by it's IP, but specify the domain to use for the certificate. Even though there was no `A` record for `example.com` mapping to this IP, I was able to trick it into thinking it was being connected by that domain.

```
curl https://example.com/path --resolve example.com:<IP>
```

Is there anything like this in Nginx?

Comment: Have you tried using the `proxy_ssl_name` directive?

Comment: @RichardSmith No, but that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like `proxy_ssl_name` might be what you are looking for:

For example:

```
proxy_set_header Host example.com;
proxy_ssl_name        example.com;
proxy_pass            https://1.2.3.4;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_name) for details.